# Is a state monad with two state variable types (in and out) still a monad?

Tags: monads, state-monad, category-theory

Haskell's state monad `State s a` forces me to keep the same type of `s` during the whole do block. But since the state monad is really just a function, what if I define it as `State i o a = State (i -> (o, a))`?. The `return` and `bind` functions would look exactly the same as in the standard state monad, but with the types changed:

```
return :: a -> State st st a
bind :: (State i o a) -> (a -> (State o o' b)) -> (State i o' b)
```

I don't think is possible to implement `Monad` in Haskell using this definition because it expects a single `State i o` type in bind (only `a` can change). But this question is not about Haskell but about whether this would technically be a monad or not. Or if not, would it be some kind of superset of a monad (such that all the monad laws still apply but has some extra features)?

This is something I found would be useful in another language I'm working on, which is based on lambda calculus, so I'm using Haskell as a reference. I just don't want this to break other stuff later on where I'd expect the monad laws to apply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is an *indexed* Monad. See e.g. the definition in `category-extras`:

The [definition of an indexed Monad](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/category-extras-0.52.1/docs/Control-Monad-Indexed.html):

```
class IxApplicative m => IxMonad m where
  ibind :: (a -> m j k b) -> m i j a -> m i k b
```

The [State indexed Monad](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/category-extras-0.52.1/docs/Control-Monad-Indexed-State.html):

```
class IxMonad m => IxMonadState m where
  iget :: m i i i
  iput :: j -> m i j ()
```

Comment: Actually this is exactly it. Apparently is not really a monad but something close, but since it has the exact same implementation as the state monad I don't see how it'd violate any of the monad rules or have any unexpected results.